Are fedoras Lo Yilbash on a woman
According to Halacha, are Fedoras considered Lo Yilbash for a woman to wear? Or no, even though they are often worn by males, are they not considered men’s apparel that women are  by halacha prohibited from wearing?

I believe a beret would be more appropriate for a woman to wear. Fedoras are mostly worn by men

Noteworthy: According to wikipedia, fedoras originally gained popularity as a woman's accessory, before they became popular for men.

@chortkov2 - more than that, the hat first appeared in a play called Fédora where Sarah Bernhardt playing Princess Fédora Romazoff wore a soft felt hat and started the fashion.

@chortkov2 Not relevant nowadays though

As long as the garment is worn by women generally that they sell it in the women's section of a department store, it is not a problem of lo silbash.
The exact guideline (based on Darkei Teshuva 182, 13) is more along the lines of, if you would see her wearing this item, would your immediate reaction be "she's wearing a man's garment!" or not?
The fact that certain items are sold only in men's stores or vice versa does not really affect this halacha.
Therefore, even if she would wear a men's fedora, if there is no noticeable difference that the average person would notice and think she's wearing a man's garment, it's permitted.

Is that link to your website?

Usually spam get deleted in Stack Exchange. @DoubleAA.

When do women ever wear fedoras? It is a man's garment.
